# How do I get a users response in Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

How do I get the users response from a question asked to the user from the slot and display a response through code?

---

**Example:**

**Alexa Skill:** *What is your name?*

**User:** *My Name is Yuri Alves*

**Alexa Skill:** *Hello Yuri Alves*

Comment: What language and sdk version are you using in your endpoint?

Comment: @UssamaZubair I am using node.js and I think it is version 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the slot value by following 2 methods in Node.js.

**OLD Method**

```js
let slot_value = this.event.request.intent.slots.slot_name.value;
```

**NEW Method**

```js
let slot_value = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.slot_name.value;
```

You can easily output this slot value in **responseBuilder**.

Comment: Thank you @UssamaZubair